# Swift 4 make round image on map

Tags: swift, label, rounding, mkannotation

I want to make a round image on map. Image size is 200 *200px, but something is wrong with my cornerRadius after transform. Can someone help me?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annoView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: selectedAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "")

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation){
        return nil
    }
    if(annotation.title! == "Hej"){
        annoView.image = UIImage(named: "Hej")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.3, y: 0.3)
        annoView.transform = transform
        annoView.layer.cornerRadius = 100
        annoView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: annoView.frame.size.width/2, y: annoView.frame.size.height/2, width: 200,height: 30))
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7215686275, green: 0.8862745098, blue: 0.5921568627, alpha: 1)
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "Hej"
        annoView.addSubview(label)    
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't even returning the `annoView` from the function, so how do you know something is wrong with the `cornerRadius`? Moreover, you should specify what's wrong, _"something is wrong"_ does not make your question on-topic.

Comment: try to set `annoView.clipsToBounds = true `

Comment: I am returning it, but I forgot to add it here.

Comment: The problem is that my image is not round after I use cornerRadius and it didnt help with annoView.clipsToBounds = true.

Comment: @DavidRuland i'm tested  you code this is the output  https://ibb.co/ermO1J  I do not know where your problem is but you have to check the size of the image and prefer changing its size